# How to get users avatar from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I haven't found any way to do that.

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
            _webApiServiceConfiguration.Domain,
            _webApiServiceConfiguration.DomainAccessUserName,
            _webApiServiceConfiguration.DomainAccessPassword))
{
    UserPrincipal userAd = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,user.USERID);
}
```

I'm using the `UserPrincipal` class to get user data from AD. Is there a way to get his picture? Client has such a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the photo of the user from the `UserPrincipal` class - you'll have to go "one level deeper", e.g. get the underlying `DirectoryEntry` object, and then figure out which AD property is holding your picture.

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
            _webApiServiceConfiguration.Domain,
            _webApiServiceConfiguration.DomainAccessUserName,
            _webApiServiceConfiguration.DomainAccessPassword))
{
    UserPrincipal userAd = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,user.USERID);

    // if not null, get the underlying DirectoryEntry
    if (userAd != null) 
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = userAd.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

        // if de is not null
        if (de != null) 
        {
            // get the property in question - possibly the "photo" property
            if(de.Properties["photo"] != null)
            {
                 // unlike a database column, an AD property can contain *multiple* values....

            }
        }
}
```

Also: those "binary" properties are often encoded in AD so don't expect to find the exact binary bytes for the photo right in the property - you might need to do some conversions or something......

You might want to search for "Getting photo from Active Directory" or something - there's a lot of posts on exactly how to do this. E.g. [this question & answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02690cfa-c2c1-43d7-9f82-7d210cb86267/c-code-to-add-and-retrieve-user-photos-from-active-directory?forum=csharpgeneral) shows some code - and there seem to be a `jpegPhoto` and a `thumbnailPhoto` property on the `DirectoryEntry` object, too.... (so you'll have to check which one is really populated in your AD)